# Does a Security architecuture Diagram of JAAS / SASL / PLAIN / SCRAM when used with kafka or other frameworks exists?

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, java-security, sasl

I am not an expert but am aware of the auth mechanism that works commonly with kafka.
Common usecases/implementations for kafka use SASL Plain or SASL SCRAM i.e
`security.protocol=SASL_SSL` or `security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT`(Not recommended for PLAIN mechanism)
and
`sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256` or 512 or `sasl.mechanism=PLAIN` (not recommended any more).

then I see JAAS configuration as below -
`sasl.jaas.config = org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username password`

What I don't get in the picture is how JAAS fits in the client and server architecture. Is there an architecture diagram that i can refer to to get the bigger picture. I have searched over google for security architecture for kafka and how JAAS fit's in to it, but had no luck.
Could some one help.

Comment: or the diagrams found where not in detail and so not useful

Comment: while any info will help, i want to understand how JAAS fit's in to the whole picture

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the jaas file as a java argument in the KAFKA_OPTS or in the client properties

export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/client_jaas.conf"

Using KafkaClient {}

Or using the client configuration

sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="user" 
password="psw";

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html

Or if you are using java spring framework check this documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/jaas.html

Jaas is the  file/configuration which contains the applicative user information which authenticate to the kafka cluster

Comment: could you point or makeup a diagram which shows where JAAS fits in the security architecture.

Comment: It is a file/configuration which contains the applicative user information which authenticate to the kafka cluster,